# DateTime Stamp Transformation in XSLT

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt

I'm trying to do what I thought would be a simple XSLT Transformation using Format Date function.

I'm want to transform 2012-01-18T11:47:41.877000000 to be YYYY/MM/DD format.

So my sample data set is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Users>
    <User>
        <FullName>Johnny Test</FullName>
        <DateHired>2012-01-18T11:47:41.877000000</DateHired>
    </User>
</Users>
```

and I'm trying to transform the date with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Users/User">
<xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="local-name()='DateHired'">
        <Date>
            <Value>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-date(.,'YYYY/MM/DD')" /> 
            </Value>
        </Date>
    </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: To be perfectly honest, you should nothing else but ISO 8601 for XML and M2M communication. Everything else is ill-desinged.

Comment: That xsl:when with a test on the element name is an anti-pattern. Use apply-templates and a template rule that matches DateHired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my initial post the Date format changed from 2012-01-18T11:47:41.877000000 to 01/18/2012 I still needed it in the format 2012-01-18.

I ended up taking Michael Kay's advice and using a template to solve this problem.

I created a template named reformatDate:

```
  <xsl:template name="reformatDate">
    <xsl:param name="date" />
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before($date, '/')" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-before(substring-after($date, '/'), '/')" />
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-after(substring-after($date, '/'), '/')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($year, '-', format-number($month, '00'), '-', format-number($day, '00'))"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

I called the template with the parameter called date:

```
<xsl:call-template name="reformatDate">
  <xsl:with-param name="date" select="."></xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

To solve the initial problem I would create a similar function but strip the values starting with the T (which is the time portion). This version works for XSLT vs 1 which doesn't have the nice date and datetime functions of vs 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `format-dateTime()` since you're using a dateTime instead of just a date.

You also need to update your [picture string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#date-picture-string).

Example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(.,'[Y]/[M00]/[D00]')" />
```